Which statistical test to use for comparison of influence of two independent variables?
I am conducting a research of "Comparison of Influence of Parents' and Teacher's Attitude Towards Math to Anxiety of Students in Math" Now my null hypothesis: There is no difference in influence between parents and teacher, now, what statistical test should I use to compare the influence IV: Parents and Teacher to DV: MA of Students?
I used multiple regression and my null hypothesis is β_teacher = β_parents, how can I statistically test the significance of difference when for example the difference coefficient is small?
